# Relevant linq query for the SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

My query initially was

```
select * 
from Personalization_Mapping
```

The relevant **LINQ** query was

```
List<Personalization_Mapping> list = _appDbContext.Personalization_Mapping.OrderBy(s => s.ID).ToList();
```

Now I need the relevant unique columns for which, I changed the SQL to

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    (SELECT  
         *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY ID DESC) rn
     FROM 
         Personalization_Mapping) a
WHERE 
    rn = 1
```

Could any one help me finding the equivalent LINQ query?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are entities in `Personalization_Mapping`?

Comment: its the table (Entity model)

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = _appDbContext.Personalization_Mapping.OrderByDescending(x => x.ID)
.GroupBy(x => x.CustomerID)
.Select(g => new {g, count= g.Count()})
.SelectMany(t => t.g.Select(b => b)
.Zip(Enumerable.Range(1,t.count), (j,i) => new {j.Property1, j.Property2, rn = i}));
```

Replace `Property1, Property2` with actual entities.

Now apply filter for row 1

```
result.Where(x => x.rn == 1);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: how to convert to the list List<Personalization_Mapping> list?